# Dialogflow_v2 sessions are slow

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I followed the official Dialogflow client documentation.
I am trying to get some intents for my input messages.
It takes like 30-40 seconds to get a response which is unacceptable for a chatbot.
In my example I've sent 2 messages (or more) - "test" and "hello". 
 The first request took very long and the second response (or any other following) is instant. 
It would be ok if the first request takes forever and the following are fast, but the session terminates after no user input and it starts again.
How can I speed it up or keep the session client alive?

```
def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
"""Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs.
Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
of the conversation."""
import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

for text in texts:
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
        text=text, language_code=language_code)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
    try:
        response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
    except InvalidArgument:
        raise

    print('=' * 20)
    print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
    print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
        response.query_result.intent.display_name,
        response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
    print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
        response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'private_key.json'
    DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'dialogflowslack'
    SESSION_ID = 'me'
    DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'
    text_to_be_analyzed = ["test", "hallo"]

    detect_intent_texts(
        DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID, text_to_be_analyzed, DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

Comment: Are you using webhook fulfillment in your agent? And if so, are you using Cloud Functions, or similar, for the fulfillment? If that's the case, then the initial response time you're observing might be related to a cold start on the function (or the server being used)

Comment: I m facing the same. Are you able to resolve it? I don't think it's related to cold start . Even if I ping a cloud function whenever user comes to the chat screen . It still takes time. And also if I send 2-3 messages then it should be fast but its still very slow.